# Getting an error in Java when trying to system.out.println("") 'class' or 'interface' expected in Intellij

Tags: java

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("wiggle house");
    }
}
```

I can run the code and I get the string printed, the only problem is `"wiggle house"` gives me an error.  Why is IntelliJ telling me this?

> 'class' or 'interface' expected

I thought IntelliJ knows that whatever I put in brackets in `System.out.println("")` it is just to be printed.

Is this a system error or an error on my part?

Comment: Note: There is no need to explain you are new. I think the code you have is fine. It runs, yes? `"wiggle house"` is just a string, so it shouldn't expect a class or interface there

Comment: What is the name of your file which your `main()` method is located in?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but when you just started to get into Java, and you also started by using a big complex thingy like an Java-IDE ... then, in 99.99999% of all cases, the error is on your part. Whatever you run into is a misconception, typo, ... on your side; and something that countless people ran into before, too. But dont worry, things will get better. Some day.

Answer (score 2):

Press "Alt + Enter" (-Keys) while your cursor is on the marked area,
then select "Un-Select Language/Reference".
Should be working now!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using your code

```
public class Hello {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("wiggle house");
   }
}
```

the your file name should be Hello.java or else you are not making it public as the code below also run without error even if the file name is different from Hello.java

> Note : if a class is not declared public it can contain the main method even if the class name is different from your file name

```
class Hello {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("wiggle house");
   }
}
```

Comment: How does this explain the error message they received?

Comment: I just try to provide a solution as if the class is not public. The error might not come up agin

Comment: So your answer is attempting to solve another issue, not the one in this question? How is that relevant?

Comment: @ Soririos alright what is your solution to the question above...Please

Comment: There isn't one. The code they've provided and the details they've provided show no indication that the error should occur. They are missing a [mcve]. Until they provide one, you should instead flag to close as either a non reproducible issue or as missing the MCVE.